# Objective-C calling a delegate method from a class where the delegate method resides within another class

Tags: objective-c, delegates

If I have a delegate which resides within its own header file myDelegate.h. Then I have a class (ClassOne) that implements the delegate protocol (therefore implementing the delegate function(s)). Then I create another class (ClassTwo) that has a instance variable of myDelegate. Can I then use this variable to call the function that resides in ClassOne?

Here is the code:

```
//myDelegate.h
@protocol myDelegate <NSObject>

- (BOOL)myFunction:(NSString*)sString;

@end


//ClassOne.h
@interface ClassOne : NSObject <myDelegate> {

}

- (BOOL)myFunction:(NSString*)sString;

@end

//ClassOne.m
#import "ClassOne.h"
@implementation ClassOne

- (BOOL)myFunction:(NSString*)sString
{
    //do stuff
}

@end


//ClassTwo.h
#import "myDelegate.h"
@interface ClassTwo : NSObject {
    id<myDelegate> del;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<myDelegate> del;

@end

//ClassTwo.m
#import "ClassTwo.h"
@implementation ClassTwo

- (void)aFunction:(NSString*)string
{
    [del myFunction:string];
}

@end
```

Comment: you don't have to add the delegate method to the header file as the class is already implementing the protocl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly right.

Except `myDelegate` should be `MyDelegate`. It's not a syntax error and will execute perfectly, but standard objective-c conventions say that you should *never* define a delegate with a lowercase first character.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed confirmation.

Comment: For the record, the technique for defining delegates has changed quite a bit over the years. The protocol system was less flexible in the past, and rarely ever used for delegates. But these days I believe protocols are flexible enough to be used for all types of delegates, and are the recommended approach.